# iOS Voice Rec (Open Ears API) Ojbective-c

Tags: ios, if-statement, voice

I have integrated Open Ears into my project.  But lets say i wanted to create a 'else if' and when one of the words is said by the user, their will be a action.

Here is an example of a 'else if' i have for a text field, when ever the user types one of the certain words into the text field a action will start.

```
else if ([command caseInsensitiveCompare:@"AUTOA"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        autoUpdate = 2;
        [self autoExec];
    }
```

But how can i do this same thing but with Open Ears.  So rather then when the user types in a command, the user can say a word/sentence i have in the language array, and the action will start.